# Multiple download buttons

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.3

I am creating an app that will allow users to download sound files from individual pages and email it to themselves, once the page is navigated to and the tone selected.

I would like to know if anyone knows **how to connect the *download button* that is on each page and connect it to the mail composer**. I have already figured out the Mail composer on my contact page, but when I try to connect the mail composer to the download buttons on each page nothing happens, I have tried using tags and am still lost any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the download button is your button.  And I'm assuming that each "page" is a different view controller?

If you want to be really efficient, you would create a separate class to hold your mail composer logic.

For a quick fix, you would connect your button to an IBAction in your view controller and either put the mail composer logic there or call its method from there.

Here is a quick example:

```
- (IBAction)sendProblemReport:(UIButton*)sender {  //note: connect your button here 

    UIButton *button;
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
       button = sender;
    }
    else {
       return;  //leave if not a button
    }

       //note: if you do it this way be sure to set tag values in interface builder on your button.  The other way is to have an action for each button.

       switch (button.tag) {
       case 1:
         NSURL  *fileURL1 = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:@"YOUR FILE PATH HERE"];
         NSData *soundfile = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL1];
         NSString *fileTitle = @"YOUR Nice File Name";  //sound.mp3
         [self showDiagMailSheetAttachingSoundFile:soundFile usingFileName:filename];
        break; 
        }
 }

- (void)showDiagMailSheetAttachingSoundFile:(NSData*)soundFile usingFileName:(NSString*)fileName {

    MFMailComposeViewController *diagMail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
    [diagMail setMailComposeDelegate:self];

        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [diagMail setToRecipients:@[@"fromaddress@gmail.com"]];
        [diagMail setCcRecipients:nil];
        [diagMail setBccRecipients:nil];
        [diagMail setSubject:@"subject message"];        
        [diagMail setMessageBody:nil isHTML:NO];

        [diagMail addAttachmentData:soundFile file mimeType:@"audio/mpeg" fileName:fileName];  //note: not sure of the mime type you need.

         diagMail.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
         [self presentViewController:diagMail animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
  }
  - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller
      didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    // Notifies users about errors associated with the interface
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        // @"Result: Mail sending canceled";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        // @"Result: Mail saved";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        // @"Result: Mail sent";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        // @"Result: Mail sending failed";
        break;
    default:
        // @"Result: Mail not sent";
        break;
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
      [self cancel:self];
    }];
 }
```

Note:  to put this in a separate sub class, you would use the class to simply return a "MFMailComposeViewController"  then you would present it in each view controller.  That approach is more efficient and allows you to call the same code in multiple places.

ok, hope that helps.  if not let me know.

Comment: will this way also allow me to attach each sound file to each page via the "download" button so when it is clicked the mail composer will come up with the sound file attached

Comment: yes, it should.  I'll edit the answer and include code for an attachment.

Comment: when you say connect the button do you mean connect it by cntrl drag because if so it will not connect, also do you have an e-mail I can contact you at because that would be much easier, If not no problem

Comment: yep, ctrl drag into your .m subclass file from a button from your view controller.  When the dialog box pops up make sure it says action (not outlet).  Now, when you press the button, it will execute the code in the that method - in effect, press the button and pop up the mail composer.  hope that helps

Comment: I try and do ctrl drag from my view controller and no window comes up it just drags over and nothing happens, what am I doing wrong

Comment: please make sure that the view controller in your storyboard or xib file that has the button has your sub class set as the model.  You set that in the objbect inspector.

Comment: Ok so I finally figured that part out I did not set my sub class, so I guess my last question would be how to get each individual button that I connect to have that file attached to it do I use tags or what would be the best way, for instance if someone picked a sound 1 and then mail composer would come up with that sound, how do I have set it up so when someone clicks sound 2 that will come up with sound 2 I hope that makes sense and I really do appreciate your patience and help

Comment: sounds like your getting close.  I've added some additional info to my answer. note: this is one approach using sender.tag of each button.  You could also have a separate action for each button - might be clearer but means some copy/pasting.  if you use sender.tag make sure you set the button tag in interface builder to align with your logic.

Comment: When I add the code on the sender.tag it gives me an error saying property tag not found of object type_strong id

Comment: I modified the answer to cast UIButton to sender.  If you have more issues, please post the entire method you are using.

Comment: Do you mind if I have your email so I can show your where I am getting the errors because there is two more errors that come up in case 1 and I can take a screen shot and show you what I have so far

Comment: you can email yatzikmobile@gmail.com